# Passing a Spring bean to a Camel component

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have a custom component of type `FooComponent` which is added to the route by the following lines:

```
from("foo://bar?args=values&etc")
        .bean(DownstreamComponent.class)
        ...
```

`FooComponent` creates an endpoint and consumer (of type `FooConsumer`) which in turn emits messages which get to the `DownstreamComponent` and the rest of the pipeline.

For monitoring, I need the `FooComponent` consumer to call a method on a non-Camel object, which I'm creating as a Spring bean.  The Camel pipeline is very performance sensitive so I'm unable to divide the `FooComponent` into two halves and insert the monitor call as a Camel component between them (my preferred solution, since `FooComponent` shouldn't really have to know about the monitor).  And I'm reluctant to turn the method call into a Camel Message that will be picked up by the monitoring component later in the pipeline, as the pipeline filtering becomes complicated later and I don't want to meddle with it more than necessary.

Somewhere inside `FooConsumer`, I have:

```
// in the class
@Autowired
Monitor monitor;

// inside the consumer's run method
monitor.noticeSomething();
```

The problem is that `monitor` will never be set to the Monitor bean which is created in the rest of the application.  As I understand it, it's because `FooConsumer` itself is not visible to Spring -- an object of that type is created normally inside `FooComponent`.

So, how can I get `FooComponent` to find the `Monitor` instance that it needs to use?

- Can I pass it in when the route is created?  This seems tricky because the definition is a faux URL `"foo://bar?args=values&etc"`; I haven't found how to pass Java objects that way.
- Can I get Spring to find that `@Autowired` annotation inside `FooConsumer` and inject the monitor object somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a singleton instance of Monitor you ought to be able to @Autowire it in the FooComponent class. As Camel will let Spring dependency inject when creating the FooComponent.

Then you can pass on the monitor instance when you create the endpoint / consumer from your component.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do is to create a `Monitor` property on the `FooComponent` class, and wire it in like any other bean.

```
<bean id="monitorBean" class="my.Monitor"/>

<bean id="foo" class="my.FooComponent">
    <property name="monitor" ref="monitorBean"/>
</bean>
```

Then in your `FooConsumer`, when you need to get hold of the monitor, call:

```
Monitor monitor = ((FooComponent) getEndpoint().getComponent()).getMonitor();
```

If you were changing the monitor bean on a per-endpoint basis, you could use Camel's nifty `#` syntax to locate a bean with that id, and inject it into an Endpoint property.

```
foo:something?monitor=#monitorBean
```

Then to use it in your `FooConsumer` you simply say:

```
Monitor monitor = ((FooEndpoint) getEndpoint()).getMonitor();
```

Comment: Interesting, but we're not actually using an XML config.  Is there an equivalent in Java?

Comment: Yes, just set the Monitor instance directly on the FooComponent.

Comment: Thanks Jake, I've not tried it but it might be a nice alternative to the autowiring.