# Camel atmosphere-websocket component : cannot get events onOpen/onClose/onError from WebsocketHandler

Tags: websocket, apache-camel, atmosphere

I am doing integration websocket and camel and choose existed atmosphere-websocket component.

My steps:

1) added to web.xml

```
<!-- Camel servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CamelWsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.atmosphere.websocket.CamelWebSocketServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Camel servlet mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CamelWsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/camel/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

2) added to spring applicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id="websocketProcessor" class="mypackage.WebsocketProcessor" />

<camelContext id="main" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="atmosphere-websocket:///chat"/>
        <process ref="websocketProcessor"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

3) used chrome-extension to connect to websocket using 
   url : ws://localhost:8080/MyApp/camel/chat

Result:

works fine I can connect and send messages 
but for some reason I see that Apache Camel 2.16.0 (CamelContext: main) is starting twice.

But the main point I need to have my own map with websocket session key and user object so I need to have access to onOpen/onClose/onError methods in org.apache.camel.component.atmosphere.websocket.WebsocketHandler .

Any suggestions how  can I do this? Maybe the component should be extended to support this feature?

Thanks,

Comment: I fixed starting camel twice by changed the order load servlets on start web.xml and moved creating camel rout from spring context xml to Java. The only issue left how to notify my application about websocket events onOpen/onClose/onError which is happening in WebsocketHandler .

Comment: As experiment I used this advice to solve my problem . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224264/passing-a-spring-bean-to-a-camel-component   But this is dirty. Waiting for some good advice